# Openshift : phpMyAdmin alternative for python mySql

Tags: openshift

I created a python app and add mySql as database. I can not add phpMyAdmin . Is there any other visual interface like phpMyAdmin for my python mySql database to interact with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that you would not be able to add phpMyAdmin is if you are running a scaled application.  Adding the phpMyAdmin cartridge is not dependent on what type of web framework cartridge you are using.

If you still can't / don't want to use phpMyAdmin, you can always use port forwarding and install something like MySQL WorkBench locally and use it.

Port forwarding:  https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html